# data in one cell unlocks another

Tags: excel, vba

I want cell f21 to be locked if there is no entry (its a time entry if that is important) in f17.  If a time is entered into f17, then f21 is subsequentially unlocked.  Here's my code.  It doesn't work at all.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 17) = blank Then
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(6, 21)).Locked = True
Else
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(6, 21)).Locked = False
End If
End Sub
```

What is wrong?

Comment: **You have not defined *blank***

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worksheet needs to be protected for this to work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Cells(6, 21).Locked = IsEmpty(Trim(Cells(6, 17))

End Sub
```

If you set the `UserInterfaceOnly` to True when protecting a worksheet you will not have to unprotect the worksheet to programmable make changes.

`ActiveSheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True`

Comment: I've added unprotect and protect lines to this code, but still the lock status of the cell does not change. Thoughts?

Comment: You will need to initialize the process but after a value is changed on the worksheet it should work properly.

Comment: is the } supposed to be there?  either way, I get a syntax error.  this should be easy but instead, frustrating

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way without the Range method

```
If ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 17) = blank Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 21).Locked = True
Else
    ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 21).Locked = False
End If
```

Comment: I've added unprotect and protect lines to this code, but still the lock status of the cell does not change. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm still not getting this right for some reason. It seems like it should be easy enough and very straightforward